# How to create custom sliding Menu bar without using actionbar in android?

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I would like design sliding menu bar on my layout button click or slide the screen : 
[image]

**on menu button click :**

[image]

Comment: And what have you done to acomplish that? What's exactly your problem? Maybe you should just look for a library doing what you need?

Comment: on my layout have menu button which is not on action bar ..and this button click open sliding bar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [SlidingMenu from GitHub](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) which is an OpenSource Android library.

If you don't want to use the menu bar from the library, you can create a custom view and include it to your Activity. And to open the SlidingMenu, you can set onClickListenner to your `Button` in the custom Menu bar.

Based from another answer, you have to extend `SherlockActivity`, and create a **`menu.xml`** which will be your custom menu layout.

Then just add those few lines in your `onCreate` method.

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```